# Hacer animacion en boton tanto al hacer clic como al hacer submit con enter

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.btn_animated{
    width: 18%;
  
}
.btn_animated:focus{
  -webkit-animation: jello-horizontal 0.5s both;
          animation: jello-horizontal 0.5s both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes jello-horizontal {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
              transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
      }
      30% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1);
              transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1);
      }
      40% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1);
              transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1);
      }
      50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1);
              transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1);
      }
      65% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1);
              transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1);
      }
      75% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1);
              transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
              transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
      }
  }
```

```html
<form action="accion.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="pass"  >
<input type="submit" value="Enviarlo" class="btn_animated">
</form>
```

Hola, este es mi archivo.html lo que quiero es que si pulso enter (submit) en el input de texto el boton "Enviarlo" haga la misma animacion como si le hubiera hecho clic en el

en resumen:  necesito que tanto como al pulsar enter en el input o al pulsar el boton haga la misma animacion el boton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo hay que escuchar cuando el formulario sea enviado y pasar foco al botón:

```js
// Obtener todos los formularios
let forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');

// Recorrer formularios para asignar evento a cada uno
forms.forEach(form => form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    // Animar botón enviándole el foco
    e.target.querySelector('.btn_animated').focus();
}));
```

```css
.btn_animated{
    width: 18%;
  
}
.btn_animated:focus{
  -webkit-animation: jello-horizontal 0.5s both;
          animation: jello-horizontal 0.5s both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes jello-horizontal {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
              transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
      }
      30% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1);
              transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1);
      }
      40% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1);
              transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1);
      }
      50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1);
              transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1);
      }
      65% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1);
              transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1);
      }
      75% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1);
              transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
              transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
      }
  }
```

```html
<form action="accion.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="pass"  >
<input type="submit" value="Enviarlo" class="btn_animated">
</form>

<form action="accion.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="pass"  >
<input type="submit" value="Enviarlo" class="btn_animated">
</form>

<form action="accion.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="pass"  >
<input type="submit" value="Enviarlo" class="btn_animated">
</form>
```

Comment: Amigo gracias era justo lo que buscaba, pero tengo un pequeñlo problema, si agrego otro form no lo hace con el segundo si no que solo funciona en el primer form y no en los demas como hago en ese caso? gracias de antemano

Comment: Listo, actualicé la respuesta.